# unexplained request on appengine cuota detail

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a page, I use it as an application on facebook.
it have no users no visits, but quota details shows me 22% of frontend at the end of day.
in logs there is no request. why?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments to this post Understanding "['Frontend Instance Hours'](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/GZmR7CcFhwM)", also read the information in the [billing docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#idle_instances)  and in the [performance settings docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Number_of_Idle_Instances).

Comment: my problem was 5 task of the default queue. reuquest performed them to an uri I can not remember, and it returned the code 500 over and over again